# How to create a list with dynamic variables

Tags: django, django-urls

I have a standard `urlpatterns` that I use for every model I want to provide `CRUD` for:

E.g. for the model `Company` this is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('company/create', CompanyCreate.as_view(), name='company_create'),
    path('company/list', CompanyList.as_view(), name='company_list'),
    path('company/detail/<int:pk>/', CompanyDetail.as_view(), name='company_detail'),
    path('company/update/<int:pk>/', CompanyUpdate.as_view(), name='company_update'),
]
```

For the model `Person` this is:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('person/create', PersonCreate.as_view(), name='person_create'),
    path('person/list', PersonList.as_view(), name='person_list'),
    path('person/detail/<int:pk>/', PersonDetail.as_view(), name='person_detail'),
    path('person/update/<int:pk>/', PersonUpdate.as_view(), name='person_update'),
]
```

Is there a way I can shortcut building URL patterns like this by just providing a `model_name` input? E.g.

```
model_list = ['company','person','car']

for model in model_list:
    urlpatterns = [
        path('%s/create', %sCreate.as_view(), name='%s_create' %model),
        path('%s/list', %sList.as_view(), name='%s_list' %model),
        path('%s/detail/<int:pk>/', %sDetail.as_view(), name='%s_detail' %model),
        path('%s/update/<int:pk>/', %sUpdate.as_view(), name='%s_update', %model),
    ]
```

Comment: I doubt it because one urls.py belongs to one app only or to the project. When it belongs to project it is to load those suffixes from the particular app. However there may be a workaround which I don't know. My question is why you want to do this?

Comment: @Amit, simply DRY. If you have 100 models with the same URL structure it seems pointless to type them all out.

Comment: I see your point. It is very valid. After all Django promotes DRY heavily. However if you are dealing with 100 apps, you are already into a complicated project which is going to take significant time. Typing few extra lines may not differ by much. However your point is very valid. I am upvoting your question and hoping to learn another new trick about Django. All the best.

Comment: Have you looked into frameworks to support this, eg the Django REST framework? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/6-viewsets-and-routers/ looks relevant - you'd still have to define the `ViewSet`s but it at least cuts down on the boilerplate. And if you make your viewsets expose the url prefix you could replace your `model_list` example with a tuple of the known `ViewSet` classes and register those. This is not something I've done myself, though.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yes but then I would not be able to use the Django template system

Comment: OK. Are your views subclasses of the Django generic class based views? Based on the name pattern/`as_view()` examples above it looks like they are. If they all set the `model` attribute (as they usually would) that could let you build a map from model classes to their associated views and iterate over it to add them to urlpatterns. It's a little obfuscatory, and you might need to put some further control into which defined view classes you include in the map, but it could work. After all, it's only the resolution of the view class itself that your above code can't handle.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper yes they are. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to dynamically create the paths. In general I would recommend against this, or at least proceeding with caution - it's useful to be able to eyeball what URIs your application responds to, and errors in dynamic path creation could lead to exposing behavior you didn't intend. But because `urlpatterns` is pure Python you can do this.

To do this, you need a) a way to discover what views exist that you want to auto-create patterns for and b) a way to create the `path` instance for each such view.

For the first part, one simple approach is to iterate through the return value of `dir(views_module)` and filter based on some criteria. EG, here I'm going to assume that you still have predefined list of the models you want to cover (as shown in your question) and that any view instance with a `model` attribute value that's in that list is potentially valid. You might benefit from being more restrictive if, say, you have specialized views you don't want to include.

So that's something like:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView, DetailView, UpdateView

import views # use your actual module here

model_list = ['company','person','car']
models_to_register = frozenset(model_list)

model_views = [possible_view for possible_view in dir(views) \
               if isinstance(possible_view, (CreateView, ListView, DetailView, UpdateView)) \
                  and getattr(possible_view, 'model', None) in models_to_register]
```

Then you need a way to create the `path` objects from each view. You'll have the view object itself already, so you need a route and (optionally but a good idea) a name.

Both route and name in your example are built by knowing the operation the view implements and the name of the model the view covers.

For the name, each view has a `model` attribute, as checked in the list comprehension, so you can use the model's `verbose_name` or `verbose_name_plural` properties or define something custom.

For the operation, I'd check the class hierarchy of the generic views. So something like this:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView, ListView, DetailView, UpdateView

def operation_from_model_view(model_view):
    if isinstance(model_view, CreateView):
        return 'create'
    elif isinstance(model_view, ListView):
        return 'list'
    elif isinstance(model_view, DetailView):
        return 'detail'
    elif isinstance(model_view, EditView):
        return 'update'
    else:
        # unrecognized view type
        return None

def path_from_model_view(model_view):
    model_name = model_view.model.verbose_name
    operation = operation_from_model_view(model_view)
    if not operation or not model_name:
        # not expected for name, possible for operation
        return None
    route = '%s/%s/' % (model_name, operation)
    if operation == 'detail' or operation == 'update':
        route = route + '<int:pk>/'
    path_name = '%s_%s' % (model_name, operation)
    return path(route, model_view.as_view(), name=path_name)
```

Then add them to your `urlpatterns`, filtering out any `None`s:

```
urlpatterns = [path for path in (path_from_model_view(view) for view in model_views) \
               if path is not None]
```

Or on 3.8 you can use the "walrus" assignment operator to do something like `urlpatterns = [path for view in model_views if path := path_from_model_view(view) is not None]`.

This is all untested - there may be syntax errors. And if you have views that are instances of those four base views in your module that cover your listed model classes you'll register paths to them - I no longer remember offhand whether that's an exception trigger or just clobbers the older definition. If you have a small enough number of views you might want to move the path from view code into a mixin of its own and have only the views you want to auto-register inherit from it - that would come closer to being explicit about what URLs your application offers. But if you have few enough views for that you might have few enough views to just manually list them in your urls.py instead of doing any of this.